# libevent : whether event can be triggered if the related socket is closed by local program

Tags: network-programming, libevent

if I add an event for a connection socket which is returned by accept(), as below

```
    event_set(&conn_ev, connfd, EV_READ|EV_PERSIST, on_recv, NULL);
    event_base_set(base, &conn_ev);
    event_add(&conn_ev, NULL);
```

if at sometime, the local program(not the peer) closes the socket, will the `conn_ev` be triggered?
if so, how to detect whether whether the event is due to the closing of the socket?

is it recv(connfd,..) returns -1 and errno is set `EBAD` or any other cases?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All sockets are marked as readable if the socket is nicely closed by the other end, with `read` returning zero. When an error is received they are marked either read- or write-able, with `read` or `write` returning `-1`.

See e.g. the [socket(7) manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) for a table of states.

Comment: I mean the local program, not the other end

Comment: @user1944267 You want to know when you close the socket yourself? That's up to you to keep track of, by e.g. removing the closed socket from all sets used for polling.